# Search form not showing correct results

Tags: wordpress, search

What's wrong with my search form on [this](http://india.thefalljourney.com/) site?
When I search for something, it shows all the posts, not just the ones that meet the search criteria.

This is the search form code:

```
<?php $search_text = "search"; ?>

<form method="get" id="search-bg"  action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/"> 

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>"  
    name="st" id="search-form"  
    onblur="javascript: if( this.value != 'search') { this.value = 'search'; this.style.color = '#888888'; }"  
    onclick="javascript: if( this.value == 'search') { this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000000'; }"
    ) 
    {this.value = '';}" />
<input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit" />

</form>
```

Also, if I copy above code to `search-form.php` and replace it with `<?php search-form(); ?>` or `<?php get_search_form( $echo ); ?>` in `sidebar.php`, will it function the same?

Comment: did you make any modifications to searchform.php?

Comment: No, I didn't. But `searchform.php` is not even referenced inside my sidebar design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's what was wrong:

since I just copied my home page template to `search.php`, it has this code in it:

```
<?php query_posts( array(
  'posts_per_page' => 16,
  'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )).'&order=ASC');?>
```

so that's why the search didn't work. After I removed it, it worked flawlessly.

So these are my final codes:

`sidebar.php`:

```
<aside>

<a href="http://facebook.com/username" id="facebook"></a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/IndiaTheFall" id="twitter"></a>


<?php get_search_form( $echo ); ?>


<div id="categories">
    <div id="categories-title"><h6><a href="/categories">Categories</a></h6></div>

    <ul><h11><?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?></h11></ul>

</div>

 <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Widgets')) : else : ?>

 <!-- All this stuff in here only shows up if you DON'T have any widgets active in this zone -->

<?php endif; ?>

</aside>
```

`searchform.php`:

```
    <?php $search_text = "search"; ?>

<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>"  
    name="s" id="search-form"  
    onblur="javascript: if( this.value != 'search') { this.value = 'search'; this.style.color = '#888888'; }"  
    onclick="javascript: if( this.value == 'search') { this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000000'; }"
    ) 
    {this.value = '';}" />
        <input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit" />

</form>
```

`search.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Nav Menu')); ?>
                    </nav>

<div id="main-content-archive">

<h85 class="inner_text_shadow"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h85>

<div id="clear-box">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> 

<?php    $bg_image = post_thumb( get_the_post_thumbnail() );?>  

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="post-bg" style="background: #777777 url(<?php echo $bg_image;?>);">

        <div id="title-bg">
            <div class="transparency"></div>
            <div class="title"><h10><?php the_title(); ?></h10></div>
        </div>

</div></a>  <!-- END post-bg -->

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>No posts meet your criteria.</h2>

<?php endif; ?> 

</div> <!-- END post_class function -->


<div id="nav"><h12><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?></h12></div>

</div> <!-- END main-content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And that's it... Everything works fine now!
Thanks for all your help...

Comment: glad you figured it out. If I was helpful at all please give me an upvote. Thanks

Comment: Don't really like when someone asks for an upvote (I would give you one after I marked my answer as correct). Thanks for your help, mate.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the default id values. I don't know if this is your problem but it might be:

```
<?php $search_text = "search"; ?>

<form method="get" id="searchform"  action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/"> 

<input id="s" type="text" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>"  
    name="st" id="search-form"  
    onblur="javascript: if( this.value != 'search') { this.value = 'search'; this.style.color = '#888888'; }"  
    onclick="javascript: if( this.value == 'search') { this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000000'; }"
    ) 
    {this.value = '';}" />
<input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit" />

</form>
```

Comment: This didn't work. Search still doesn't give the right results and the design is obviously screwed up as well...

Comment: what theme are you using? Do you know if it has a custom search function (look for a php file with the word search in it)? Can you post your relevant function code in search-form.php?

Comment: There is no relevant code in `search-form.php` because it is not referenced in my theme. Search form code is written directly inside the theme. It's a custom theme (made from scratch) that I'm trying to tweak now so that I get everything to work.

Comment: then please post the search form code that is "written directly inside  the theme". The problem does not appear to be with the code you posted above - it is a relatively straightforward GET that sends the search term. The problem is with the function or the search results page.